# 16gb of my 32gb RAM memory is "hardware reserved" and not usable

Tags: windows-10, memory, bios, motherboard

I have a B450 GAMING PRO CARBON AC (MS-7B85) motherboard and for three years I have been using 16gb ram (Corsair 16GB (2x8GB) DDR4 3000MHz CL15 Vengeance LPX) without any issues. Today I decided to buy 2x8=16gb more RAM (the exact same product as before). I put them in to the remaining last slots firmly securing them in place. When running `dxdiag`, the memory seems to be recognized:

[image: dxdiag]

However, in the task manager only 16gb is available and it says that another 16gb is "hardware reserved":

[image: Taskmanager]

This is the information in the BIOS:

[image: BIOS]

How do I enable all of my 32gb of ram?

Comment: Is it possible for my motherboard to be compatible with only 2x8gb RAM and not compatible with 4x8gb RAM, even if the RAM sticks are 100% identical?

Comment: The motherboard supports 128GB of RAM, so this RAM configuration should be acceptable. How are they installed, I believe in this board, you put ram "pair" 1 in slots 2&4 (DIMMA2 & DIMMB2) and ram "pair" 2 in slots 1&3 (DIMMA1 & DIMMB1)... If you have them in differently, like 1&2 and 3&4 for example, the results could be unpredictable. https://i.imgur.com/rMazXt0.png

Comment: @acejavelin What do you mean pairs? All 4 are the exact same product. The first two I bought and used successfully for 3 years are installed in slot 2 and 4, the RAM I bought today is installed in slots 1 and 3.

Comment: Does the new set get recognized and work properly without the old set installed?

Comment: @Yorik Yes, there seems to be no problem with the new ram sticks by themselves.